# Pipe Subprocess File not found Python

Tags: python, unix, subprocess, stdout, popen

I'm getting an error "File not found" in using `subprocess.Popen`

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("awk -v s='FILE_NAME' 'index($0, s) == 1' input | awk '{print$2}'",stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

file_name = proc.stdout.read()
```

Can you please help me to get it sorted out?
(`input` is there in the directory from where i'm running the script. This command is working when i use it in terminal)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try it with `shell=True`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Any idea why shell=True is necessary here?

Comment: Because as soon as you have a string containing more than just an executable name, e.g. space separated arguments, pipes, etc, these are things that need to be interpreted by a shell.